# SVM : support vector has margin of 0?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to generate the separating hyperplane of binary classification for 3D points.

Here are my points, which are linearly separable.

```
Class 0: [[0,0,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [0.5,0.4,0.4]]
Class 1: [[1,3,1], [2,0,2], [1,1,1]]
```

From `sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='linear')`, the following is produced:

```
w = clf.coeff_ = [ 1.   0.5  0.5]
b = clf.intercept_ = -2.0
sv = clf.support_vectors_ = 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The understanding is, if `w.dot(x)+b` returns a negative value, then x is of Class 0; if positive value, then Class 1. However, `w.dot([1,1,1])+b = 0` !! This means that `[1,1,1]`, which is a **support vector** from Class 1, **lies** on the separating plane..... while no SVs from Class 0 lie on the sep. plane.

**SO MY QUESTION IS...**

My data is linearly separable, so theoretically an SVM should have margins >0 for both classes. But here, my SVM has a =0 for class1 and >0 margin for class0. Why is this the case? And if my hyperplane is incorrect, how can I calculate the correct hyperplane? Thank you.

**CODE**

```
from sklearn import svm
X0 = [[0,0,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [0.5,0.4,0.4]]
Y0 = [0] * len(X0)
X1 = [[1,3,1], [2,0,2], [1,1,1]]
Y1 = [1] * len(X1)
X = X0 + X1
Y = Y0 + Y1
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, Y)
sv = clf.support_vectors_
w = clf.coef_[0] 
b = clf.intercept_[0]
print([w.dot(X0[i])+b for i in range(len(X0))]) # negative class
print([w.dot(X1[i])+b for i in range(len(X1))]) # positive class
```

Answer (score 0):

YES! You are correct in your explanation that, if `w.dot(x)+b` returns a negative value, then x is of Class `0`;

Here is where it needs to be emphasized a bit more carefully!

The classification is made based on THE SIGN!

It is `SIGNUM(w.dot([x])+b)`, `w.dot([1, 1, 1]) + b = 0`, 0 is considered `POSITIVE`! and that's why `[1, 1, 1]` is considered to be of class 1

`X1 = [[1,3,1], [2,0,2], [1,1,1]]`

`clf.predict(X1)`

You get

`array([1, 1, 1])`

For points in 2D, you FIRST find a line that separates the data correctly. This line is called the decision boundary! NOW IN THIS DECISION BOUNDARY? `w.dot([1, 1, 1]) + b = 0` Then what you want to do is, Find the widest area around that one line (called the MARGIN/MAXIMUM SEPARATING HYPERPLANE/WIDEST ROAD) that maximizes the distance between points in the two classes!

When the classes are perfectly separable?

At one end of your margin that are governed by Support Vectors? `w.dot([1, 1, 1]) + b = -1`

At the other end of your margin that are governed by Support Vectors? `w.dot([1, 1, 1]) + b = +1`

BUT, When the classes are NOT perfectly separable? You can have a margin that PERFECTLY LIES on the DECISION BOUNDARY ITSELF! THIS DEPENDS ON YOUR DATA!, In your case, one part of your MARGIN/MAXIMUM SEPARATING HYPERPLANE/WIDEST ROAD lies on your DECISION BOUNDARY! And it can't be helped!

Comment: thanks for your response! So your answer to my question is "it can't be helped" ? I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. My data is linearly separable, so theoretically an SVM should have margins >0 for both classes. But here, my SVM has a =0 for class1 and >0 margin for class0. Is there a more theoretical/conceptual answer to this?